# Adding DC voltages of PSU

Tags: dc

I need to add two voltages together that share a common ground (power supply from computer). I tried using bridge rectifiers and Op-Amps.

Comment: You have to give a lot more information. What do you mean by "add voltages together"? What are you trying to do? And what is you problem/why is it not working?

Comment: If you mean that you want to get power from it at a higher voltage, then that will not work.

Comment: @Jack: please fix your question. If you are trying to add two power supply voltages to generate a higher voltage then please make that clear in your question. (If they're sharing a common ground then you can't.) Please also write full sentences ("I need to ..."), capitalise properly ("add", not "Add", "op-amps") and punctuate.

Comment: @Neamus, I was trying to get Jack to take some responsibility for his post. "Op-Amp" is not a proper noun so it doesn't get capitalised. Thanks for the tidy-up anyway.

Comment: @Transistor I appreciate the feedback I'll make sure I'll remember for nextime.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have 2 different voltages that you want to add together? So for example you have 3V and 2V and you want to add them to produce 5V?

For this, you can use a summing amplifier configuration. There are 2 types. Inverting and non-inverting (pretty self explanatory).

The non-inverting summing amplifier looks like this:

[image]

*Picture taken from [AN-31 document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla140c/snla140c.pdf) (a fantastic resource for operational amplifier use)*

If you keep the resistors all the same value, then you can get a gain of 1 and you will just sum the inputs. Changing the resistors R1 and R2 can change the gain.

If I have misunderstood anything, then please clarify what you mean by editing your question.

*Note that this will only sum voltages if you have an appropriate supply rail. If your supply is 12V, you cannot sum 10V and 5V for example. You need the appropriate headroom*

Comment: A summing amp will also not drive very much of a load.

Comment: @RDrast It answers the question as it stands though. There is no info on load, overall supply, or anything. With the question as it is, this answers it.